# libGDX: the screen disposed more than one time (IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: java, libgdx

I created `Array<InputProcessor>();`, and I added to it `stage` and `this` (which my class implements `InputProcessor` like that:

```
public MyClass implements Screen, InputProcessor {
    private Stage stage;
    .....
    private InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer;
    private Array<InputProcessor> arrayProcessor = new Array<InputProcessor>();

    @Override
    public void show() {
        .....

    arrayProcessor.add(this);
    arrayProcessor.add(stage);
    inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
    inputMultiplexer.setProcessors(arrayProcessor);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);

    }

    .....

}
```

I called `touchUp` method firstly which removing inputProcessor:

```
@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    isTouchUp = true;
    return false;
}
```

In `render` method:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    .....
    if(isTouchUp) {
       arrayProcessor.removeValue(this, true);
       isTouchUp = false;
    }
}
```

Secondly, I called `touchUp` method from listener of the `Image` actor which agian adding inputProcessor:

```
listener = new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
         arrayProcessor.clear();
         arrayProcessor.add(MyClass.this);
         arrayProcessor.add(stage);
        }
}
image.addListener(listener);
```

I repeated the removing and the adding for inputProcessor 3 times.

Until now everything works fine.

**BUT** when and I dispose `MyClass` screen and set new `Screen`,

```
((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).dispose();
((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new TestScreen());
```

`MyClass` disposed 3 times.

```
@Override
public void dispose() {
    System.out.println("MyClass diposed");
    stage.dispose();
    .....
}
```

then output appears this `Exception`:

```
MyClass diposed
MyClass diposed
MyClass diposed
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: buffer not allocated with newUnsafeByteBuffer or already disposed
```

I feel there is trivial error in my code, I don't know why :), I tried to find it but no avail.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I noticed that you keep adding and removing stuff from `arrayProcessor` instead of the multiplexer. What is the point of `arrayProcessor`?

As for why your MyClass is disposed three times, none of the code you have shared would explain why. What does your Game class's `dispose` method look like?

Comment: ...as well as your MyClass's `dispose` method in its entirety? I also find it odd that you would manually call `dispose` on your top level ApplicationListener, because that implies you are wanting to unload absolutely everything before switching screens. Surely you have at least some stuff (like a SpriteBatch instance) that you can reuse for multiple screens, right?

Comment: I found it :) I called listener three times with new class `new InputListener()`. So, your first comment is right I don't explain more about my code because listener isn't in `show` method but called inside another listener. anyway, thanks for replying on my question.